# How to read objects within Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have Javascript array which contains `User` object. I have created this array from `modelAttribute`.

```
var userList = '${userList}';     // userList is a spring model attribute
```

`userList` contains list of `User` objects. I am accessing it as

```
for(i=0;i<userList.length;i++)
    {
        if(searchKey == "" || userList[i].indexOf(searchKey) != -1)
        {   
            $('#userTable').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                  userList[i].firstName,
                  userList[i].lastName,
                  userList[i].institution,
                  userList[i].email] );
        }   
    }
```

But I am getting values as `undefined`. Initially I used Ajax call for same and it worked fine .

```
$.getJSON("lookup/users", {name:searchKey,userType:"requester"}, function(userList) {
// It works fine        
        for(i=0;i<userList.length;i++)
        {
            $('#userTable').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                  userList[i].firstName,
                  userList[i].lastName,
                  userList[i].institution,
                  userList[i].email] );
        }

    });
```

How can I access it now ?

**EDIT:**
console.log("userList :" + userList);  gives

```
userList : [org.test.dto.UserDTO@11d1c59, org.test.dto.UserDTO@302f39, org.test.dto.UserDTO@16c57b1]
```

Comment: try console.log(userList) to see what it actually contains

Comment: yes, try finding out the exact structure of the variable userList after you populate it. The structure could be different from what you think it is. Use console.log or put a break point in firebug after the assignment and check your watch block) or simply type userList in firebug console.

Comment: @VijayakrishnanK: i checked it contains object. Please check my edit.

Comment: what does "typeof userList" give? If it gives you a string, you will not be able to read it out as an array. In this case, you'll need to change the way data is being fed (a good way will be emulate how your AJAX handler lookup/users returns the data in JSON form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Ajax and Json for same and stored result in JS variable

```
userList = null; 
    $.getJSON("lookup/users", {name:"",userType:"requester"}, function(users) {
             userList = users;
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var userList = '${userList}';
```

`userList` is not an array.

Take out the quotes if it's supposed to render a javascript array.

Comment: I tried removing quotes. It gave me error
`Error: missing ] after element list
Source File: http://localhost:7009/portal/request/form/add
Line: 1006, Column: 56
Source Code:
 var userList = [org.test.dto.UserDTO@3c96a9, .....`

Comment: @YetAnotherCoder - if that's the actual source, I don't think that's even valid javascript. I get an error if I try to use `@` anywhere.  It looks to me like you need to serialize your data from whatever framework you're using to generate this list. `org.test.dto.UserDTO@11d1cd59` may be an object in your framework, but it's just an undefined / illegal name in javascript. Take a look at what the server responded in your `getJSON` function - you'll see properly serialized JSON you can use as a template.

Comment: That might be the cause. I am using `spring` framework. Is there any other simple alternative to this ?

Comment: @YetAnotherCode - I'm not familiar with spring so you might want to ask a new question. You'd just need to pull the 4 attributes out you're trying to get: `firstName`, `lastName`, etc. and put _those values_ into the array somehow. Where that happens in spring, I can't say...

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition should probably be:

```
if(searchKey == "" || userList[i].firstName.indexOf(searchKey) != -1 || userList[i].lastName.indexOf(searchKey) != -1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an error in your code. 
    for(i=0; i < users.length;i++)
is it works?

Comment: Yes. Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: if $.getJSON return userList is right, and users are same as userList. may be the error is this
for(i=0; i< users.length; i++)  =>  for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)